# Query detected badblocks from NTFS

Tags: linux, ntfs, badblocks, mkfs

When creating an ntfs partition with `mkfs.ntfs`, it does zeroing and badblocks scanning by default. But unlike `e2fsck -fccky` it does not output how many badblocks it actually found.

I would like to get an impression of the reliability of the disk, can I somehow obtain the number of bad blocks found by NTFS?

Answer (score 0):

There are no Linux utilities which offer this feature to the best of my knowledge.

Unfortunately only chkdsk from Windows shows the number of bad blocks. If you don't have a Windows licence, there are trial versions of Windows you can download and use legally.